# Correctly using rebase in Git

Tags: git, merge, push, rebase, pull

I am working in a common development project and I have a doubt on the correct use of Git Bash for merging changes to the remote branch. My colleagues are using a UI (Tortoise Git), but I would like to keep on using Git Bash.

This is what I usually do for committing and pushing my changes:

```
git commit -a -m "<commit message>"
git pull
git push
```

If there are any conflicts, I proceed as follows:

```
git commit -a -m "<commit message>"
git pull
<Solve conflicts using Tortoise Git>
git commit -a -m "<commit message>"
git push
```

My understanding is that the above is not best practice, because the log for the branch is going to get messy (with plenty of branches all around, plus a long list of diffs when I push my changes). I am being told a rebase is a better alternative as the log history is kept linear (basically commits are stashed one after the other).

**How should I modify my code to properly use the rebase function?**

Comment: git pull origin main branch --rebase  . Would help to avoid message

Comment: Add `-r` to the pull command.

Comment: Commit to a separate local branch that you periodically merge the tracking branch *into* to resolve conflicts. Once your local branch is ready, you can use rebase to simply it before merging *it* into the tracking branch before doing a git push.

Comment: Note that *better* is a matter of opinion and/or need. Is a hammer better than a screwdriver? What if you need to drive screws? What if you need to put in a nail?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to understand at first is how `git pull` works.
So according to the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull)

> More precisely, git pull runs git fetch with the given parameters and then depending on configuration options or command line flags, will call either git rebase or git merge to reconcile diverging branches.

As stated in the comments, you can use `git pull --rebase` (or `-r`).
And you will be fine. But you can actually automate it by doing:

`git config pull.rebase true` (you would probably like to add `--global` flag here)

With this config you don't need to modify the commands you are running.

And that would be all about the answer, but small note from me.
I'm personally using different config:
`git config pull.ff only`

What's the difference and why? With this config, you will fail to pull if the remote branch diverged with your local branch. And then you will be able to check what's the reason for that. (Maybe you do not expect the diversion in the first place, maybe you misspelled the branch name wrong and you almost merged different remote branch?)

From here you can proceed with first checking the logs, for example you can run
`git log <branch_name>...<origin_branch_name>`
And when you decide on what you want to do, you can run:

`git pull -r` (cause you don't want to make the history messy as you stated)

or

`git pull -ff` (Which will then create merge commit, if you decide that this is the way you want to handle it)